# Remap inside a launch file vs remapping during rosbag play

Tags: ros-melodic, roslaunch, rosbag, remapping, remap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

Goal (more of getting to know tutorial): Trying to run this particular code http://wiki.ros.org/image_pipeline/Tutorials/Simple%20image%20processor on an image from a rosbag.

Instead of changing the topic name inside the code (obviously this works), I tried the remap option in a launch file, which I thought is the better way. Tried the following two launch scripts,
launch_file1:

```
<launch>
  <node name="image_shrinker_node" pkg="image_shrinker" type="image_shrinker" output="screen">
  <remap from="/ns/camera1/image_raw" to="/camera/image_raw"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

launch_file2:

```
<launch>
  <remap from="/ns/camera1/image_raw" to="/camera/image_raw"/>
  <node name="image_shrinker_node" pkg="image_shrinker" type="image_shrinker" output="screen">
  </node>
</launch>
```

Neither seems to work. The only I could get this to work is remapping it during rosbag play as, `rosbag play bag_file.bag /ns/camera1/image_raw:=/camera/image_raw`

Can anyone help me figure out what went wrong in the launch file?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/357986/remap-inside-a-launch-file-vs-remapping-during-rosbag-play/) by [praskot](https://answers.ros.org/users/29965/praskot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 257 on 2020-07-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In both of your launch files, you are asking the `image_shrinker` node to remap its topic `/ns/camera1/image_raw` to `/camera/image_raw`. This is the wrong way around. `from` should specify the existing name, and `to` the name that you want to change it to. Because `image_shrinker` doesn't have a topic at `/ns/camera1/image_raw` the remapping rule has no effect.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2020-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [praskot](https://answers.ros.org/users/29965/praskot/) on 2020-07-26**:
Thanks Geoff. That makes sense.

Also, does that mean remap works only on the publisher's end?

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2020-07-26**:
No, remapping works just fine on the subscriber as well.

**Comment by [praskot](https://answers.ros.org/users/29965/praskot/) on 2020-07-26**:
I see!
Thanks

This works,

```
<launch>
  <node name="image_shrinker_node" pkg="image_shrinker" type="image_shrinker" output="screen">
  <remap from="/camera/image_raw" to="/ns/camera1/image_raw"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```